# Detecting dark theme in Chrome on MacOS

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome

I have a site that has a theme switcher (dark, light & reset to OS), which works fine. In MacOS I typically have my theme set to dark, only Chrome never loads the dark theme for sites that have it where they have the `prefers-color-scheme` media query present, including mine (when the manual selector is not set), whereas other browsers do.

I have added an eventListener, to listen for the change, again, it shows in all browsers but Chrome.

Tested in (all browsers and OS up to date on M1 MBP):

- Chrome (Event doesn't log to the console)
- Chrome Incognito (Event doesn't log to the console)
- Firefox Developer Edition (Event logs to the console)
- Safari (Event logs to the console)
- Edge (Event logs to the console)
- Chrome Canary (Event logs to the console)

This has bothered me for far too long, sites I know have `prefers-color-scheme: dark;` set, don't initially show me the dark theme, I have to find the manual toggle/button. Not the end of the world, I know, but it's quite frustrating.

- I opened Incognito (to rule out extensions) reloaded the page, changed my theme, nothing logged to the console
- I tried Firefox & Safari, all good there
- I tried Edge, wondering if this is a Chromium bug on MacOS, again, works perfectly
- I tried Canary and that works
- Reset Flags to Default
- Set Chrome Appearance to System
- Disabled all extensions
- Relaunched after every change I made in Chrome
- Reset all settings in Chrome (I didn't really want to do that, but I did)
- Googled it extensively, nobody appears to be having the same issue and it's been like this for ages, like well over a year.

I'm all out of options now, I don't want to reinstall Chrome as that will probably annoy me more than it has when I reset Chrome and it did nothing.

My JS Event Listener is fine, it works everywhere apart from Chrome on this Mac, it works on Windows Chrome too. The theme displays correctly on Android Chrome and iPad.

Expectation is this log should the OS theme theme to Chrome's console when I change my MacOS theme:

```
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', evt => {
  const theme = evt.matches ? "dark" : "light";
  console.log( theme );
});
```

Absolutely nothing happens, only in Chrome. When I make that OS change, My MS Teams, Safari and everything else changes theme.

This logs to the console, as expected, when I resize the window:

```
window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').addEventListener('change', evt => {
  const size = evt.matches ? "yeah" : "nah";
  console.log( size );
});
```

Just to add further, this happens on MDN, too, no change there. It's not my theme switcher, I just add an entry to localStorage when a theme is hard selected, there is a reset button that removes the entry which is selected, localStorage is empty and the data-attr is not displaying on the HTML element, so there is no issue with the way I'm doing anything with any of that. If I do choose Dark Theme, it does load the correct theme on repeat visits, it's just the system preference that is the issue.

What the issue is, is why won't that listener run in Chrome, what could I have possibly done that prevents it from even running, especially after resetting everything I can think of?

So I guess my question is, anybody run into this before and if so, what did you do to fix it?